# /joy_node when running headless

Tags: ros, joy-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have Ubuntu 20.04 running on a Jetson Nano. I recently got the Nano hooked up into my robot so I've been running it headless (no display connected) to test things after I SSH in. However, I have found that when I run

```
ros2 topic echo /joy
```

I do not receive any messages from my Sony Dual Sense controller, even though it is connected via bluetooth. However, if I plug in a display and log in to Ubuntu desktop environment and then launch my ROS2 package, then I can see all of the expected messages under /joy node.

Any thoughts on why this might be?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394474//joy_node-when-running-headless/) by [iangillespie](https://answers.ros.org/users/92128/iangillespie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2022-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solution to this was to enable automatic login for my user on the Jetson Nano.

---

Originally posted by [iangillespie](https://answers.ros.org/users/92128/iangillespie/) with karma: 36 on 2022-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1